# GCP: Can't get Compute Engine VMs to contact a specific public DNS name server after applying a DNS outbound forwarding policy

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

TL;DR SOLUTION: DIG CANNOT BE USED TO VERIFY DNS FORWARDING POLICIES AS THE DNS RESOLUTION IS PERFORMED BY THE ROOT SERVERS

I am trying to create a DNS outbound forwarding policy for forwarding DNS requests to a specific name server. It is going to be implemented in an on-prem setup, but I am currently just testing it with public DNS servers such as 1.1.1.1. I have created the DNS outbound policy, but every request from inside VMs still uses the metadata server: 169.254.169.254

CURRENT SETUP:
I have created a VPC, defined a subnet, and created a VM connected to this subnet.

```
resource "google_compute_network" "vpc-hub" {
  name = "vpc-hub"

  depends_on = [
    google_project_iam_member.assign-roles,
    google_project_service.enable_apis
  ]
}

resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "vpc-subnet-hub" {
  name          = "vpc-subnet-hub"
  ip_cidr_range = "10.0.0.0/16"
  region        = "europe-west1"
  network       = google_compute_network.vpc-hub.id
  
  depends_on = [
    google_compute_network.vpc-hub
  ]
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "hub-vm" {
  name         = "hub-vm"
  machine_type = "e2-medium"
  zone         = "europe-west1-b"

  depends_on = [
    google_compute_subnetwork.vpc-subnet-hub
  ]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "debian-cloud/debian-9"
    }
  }
  network_interface {
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.vpc-subnet-hub.name
    
    access_config {
    }
  }
  metadata_startup_script = file("${path.module}/startup_install.sh")
}
```

The startup-script installs dnsutils. Additionally, I have defined a firewall rule to be able to connect to it via SSH:

```
resource "google_compute_firewall" "ssh-rule-hub" {
  name = "demo-ssh"
  network = google_compute_network.vpc-hub.name
  allow {
    protocol = "tcp"
    ports = ["22"]
  }

  source_ranges = ["REDACTED]

  depends_on = [
    google_compute_network.vpc-hub
  ]
}
```

ISSUE:
I have created a DNS forwarding policy by specifying the public name server 1.1.1.1:

```
resource "google_dns_policy" "dns-policy" {
  name                      = "dns-policy"
  enable_inbound_forwarding = false

  enable_logging = false

  alternative_name_server_config {
    target_name_servers {
      ipv4_address    = "1.1.1.1"
      forwarding_path = "default"
    }
  }

  networks {
    network_url = google_compute_network.vpc-hub.id
  }

  depends_on = [
    google_compute_network.vpc-hub
  ]
}
```

When I SSH into the VM and attempt to use dig to send a DNS request to any domain. It always uses the internal metadata server within the compute engine - And thus does not use 1.1.1.1 to retrieve the IP. Instead the answer is always provided by the metadata server: 169.254.169.254. Why is this the case? Output from Dig can be seen below:

bash command: dig google.com

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60323
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 6, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             300     IN      A       64.233.184.101
google.com.             300     IN      A       64.233.184.139
google.com.             300     IN      A       64.233.184.102
google.com.             300     IN      A       64.233.184.100
google.com.             300     IN      A       64.233.184.113
google.com.             300     IN      A       64.233.184.138

;; Query time: 18 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 26 12:09:53 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 135
```

EDIT: output from bash command dig google.com +trace

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> google.com +trace
;; global options: +cmd
.                       510859  IN      NS      a.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      b.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      c.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      d.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      e.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      f.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      g.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      h.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      i.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      j.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      k.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      l.root-servers.net.
.                       510859  IN      NS      m.root-servers.net.
;; Received 239 bytes from 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254) in 22 ms

com.                    172800  IN      NS      k.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      b.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      l.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      i.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      e.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      j.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      a.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      f.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      g.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      d.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      c.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      m.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    172800  IN      NS      h.gtld-servers.net.
com.                    86400   IN      DS      30909 8 2 E2D3C916F6DEEAC73294E8268FB5885044A833FC5459588F4A9184CF C41A5766
com.                    86400   IN      RRSIG   DS 8 1 86400 20220510050000 20220427040000 47671 . hGerEs3N471ZCOosNSuakxBfxXh8H+qPP9UxVBakXvVfgLofu40+aNyw X9tfaNxmyFP7LUJDRBrURhNjN1cOdJhbTqa54AXvTlPbd31N5MRF3ZHT seJJLCe8Hv2UYLrnLSzAArpD2M+N0XI+3A6wR8/fE4/q0NULX0gpKxS9 Y/zHpr/Mu/2I8DLmI8sE411vSlK2MFxWj2LfQ0TAocjnmqkZQK9GfqQ4 IEDjcc2OV41JlxSKYtAy9OI3HJPfXcIrmo4aO9Qvoe1ZKn1fu46IUYpo zx1n5NgX4Ou8kOgjePMkpGMlvjLVY2KMxYdln7v4FCRB7mb1WsBp5H+3 3Sv7vQ==
;; Received 1170 bytes from 192.33.4.12#53(c.root-servers.net) in 10 ms

google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns2.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns1.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns3.google.com.
google.com.             172800  IN      NS      ns4.google.com.
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - CK0Q1GIN43N1ARRC9OSM6QPQR81H5M9A NS SOA RRSIG DNSKEY NSEC3PARAM
CK0POJMG874LJREF7EFN8430QVIT8BSM.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20220503042354 20220426031354 37269 com. vPwsL+I4ptKlrtrsZXrs/Z3/1Ebd3eBCm5f73FcuoljLz9RHDPdxfGCd rHmK3oWXZIErmCLYy6NgcpiMEM+JiqTQm/mNFhVfoFTGicCB9JwGgA3p XfgAB6w/hsNvtqTVuFsszhq4+CjXf1+ky0hFzTHACJ3bPmEeMa80ASwX EHu+vpL9LdLSZrtS68G2ieGvjrwcn6EZfmfJIly3i8UU9g==
S84BKCIBC38P58340AKVNFN5KR9O59QC.com. 86400 IN NSEC3 1 1 0 - S84BUO64GQCVN69RJFUO6LVC7FSLUNJ5 NS DS RRSIG
S84BKCIBC38P58340AKVNFN5KR9O59QC.com. 86400 IN RRSIG NSEC3 8 2 86400 20220504051944 20220427040944 37269 com. G/tnTZRrBZApHzz+bWDsUrDBa6PcH5O15adPaWvIlvIMe1FQUYFRJeMm pzJ586JzBfz5bE+5IjU0uAh6AnWrDVtryUig0CUpMVDn8mm8Axa9QTu/ 1h3hwE6HbKx/4d7hNpZIuKGH98iMKJLaYdfJHFLRV85/AOT9HdL2ihtF t2wOZ3Px0Wo6QVxpwth2hO2iLw0k/tszErnHw6BqxEAebQ==
;; Received 836 bytes from 192.41.162.30#53(l.gtld-servers.net) in 8 ms

google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.5.101
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.5.113
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.5.100
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.5.138
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.5.102
google.com.             300     IN      A       142.251.5.139
;; Received 135 bytes from 216.239.32.10#53(ns1.google.com) in 1 ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **SERVER** address 169.254.169.254 does not mean the server that responded. That address is the metadata server that knows how to forward internal (project specify) and global domain names to the correct DNS server. That address is a virtualized service that provides a number of services such as DNS, DHCP, and NTP.

Comment: 1/2 Thanks for the answer! So I understand, that the metadata server is basically the first point of contact, and that it forwards the request. When I run dig google.com +trace, it shows the route of name servers until it reaches ns1.google.com. From this I infer that 216.239.32.10 must be the final server from which the A record is returned.

Comment: 2/2 My question is then, why doesn't the metadata server attempt to contact 1.1.1.1 for the resolution? Alternatively, do you know if the dig tool is an incorrect approach to test DNS forwarding in GCP and can you recommend another approach? Or finally, would you recommend another solution in GCP for achieving DNS forwarding to a specific alternative name server? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @cbrandborg - the metadata service is an endpoint for **virtualized** services. The server **216.239.32.10** is ns1.google.com** so that indicates that 1.1.1.1 was not consulted. Edit your question with the output from **dig +trace**. The metadata server should have forwarded the request to 1.1.1.1 (there might be another server in middle). Just remember that an outbound server policy sends all requests to the other server which will block internal VPC name resolution (Cloud DNS private zones, forwarding zones, peering zones, or Compute Engine internal DNS zones).

Comment: @cbrandborg - Enable logging and review. https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/monitoring

Comment: I have updated the question with the +trace output now. As can be seen from the output it contacts several name servers in between. Regarding the disablement of internal name resolution, that is fine, since I do not want to use DNS zones in GCP for the resolution - It has to happen at a specific name server. Am I correct in the notion, that the policy indeed does not take effect as it never contacts 1.1.1.1? I will enable logging and monitor it to investigate.

Comment: @cbrandborg - Dig does not use your nameservers. Dig uses its own algorithm starting at the root servers to resolve domain names. The trace shows a normal authoritative name server search starting at the root servers. Since 1.1.1.1 is not an authoritative name server for google.com it will not be consulted. I think the only way to analyze this is to turn on logging and make a normal DNS query.

Comment: Makes so much sense. Therefore dig cannot be used to verify whether the VM forwards the DNS requests as dig resolves the requests using the root servers. I tested it by querying the VMs internal dns. As expected, this doesn't work with the forwarding policy enabled since the queries are redirected to 1.1.1.1. After consulting the logs, I can see that each request is indeed forwarded to the intended name server from inside the VM as 1.1.1.1 is listed in the destination IP - In short, it has been working the whole time. Thank you very much for the answers, John!